# Why ROC curves gives different ranking of classes than confsuion matrix?

Tags: logistic, roc, confusion-matrix

I am applying logistic regression in a imbalance class datset which has 16 classes. When I see the confusion matrix I found that best predicted class is 5 having the score of 0.97 then class 15 having the score of 0.89 and then class 7 having score of 0.46.

[image: Confusion matrix]

When I plot the ROC curve then I see the class predicted ordering 5, 15, and 14 according to AUC. What is wrong in my code or I am getting some confusion between ROC curve as I should not expect the same behaviour as confusion matrix from ROC.

[image]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, StandardScaler
log_reg_model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=50000,penalty='l1',multi_class='ovr',class_weight='balanced',solver='liblinear')

pipe=Pipeline([('polynomial_features',polynomial),('StandardScaler',StandardScaler()), ('logistic_regression',log_reg_model)])

y_test_dummies = pd.get_dummies(y_test, drop_first=False).values
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i],tpr[i], _ =  roc_curve(y_test_dummies[:,i], pipe.predict_proba(x_test)[:,i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC(area = %0.2f)' % (roc_auc[i]))
```

Comment: Accuracy and AUC don't measure the same thing, so it's not surprising that they give different numerical values.